# C# Deserializing Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, deserialization, blazor-webassembly

I try to deserialize a json response:

```
var res = await Http.GetAsync("api/endpoint");
var resBody = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var listOfDicts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>(resBody);
```

This is the json we get from the endpoint:

```
[
   {
      "key":"Activities",
      "value":{
         "Delete":[
            "string1",
            "string2",
            "string3"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

But it fails deserializing:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]. Path: $[0].key | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 20.

I don't know where to keep trying. The json seems valid to me.

Comment: Just deserialize it to `JObject`.

Comment: You misunderstand how `Dictionary`s are usually represented as JSON. The dictionary key is the JSON property name and the dictionary value is the JSON value of the JSON property. So in your case your dictionary has two keys: `"key"` and `"value"`. Now you see that the values are of different types. The first one is a simple `string` and doesn't match the expected value type of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

> The json seems valid to me.

The JSON is valid, but it's not valid as a `List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. It would be valid (at least logically) as a `List<KeyValuePair<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>`. But at the moment, it's trying to deserialize the object as a dictionary with one key of `"key"` and one key of `"value"`... with the value for the `"key"` being just `"Activities"`, which is clearly not a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

If you really want a `List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, you'd want JSON of:

```json
[
   {
      "Activities":{
         "Delete":[
            "string1",
            "string2",
            "string3"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

(I'd also say that if you know what the keys are going to be, your C# code is likely to be a *lot* clearer if you could create classes to represent the data model - that level of nested collections is going to be a pain to work with.)

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem: before the response is send, i used **`result.Reverse()`** which turned it into a `IEnumerable`. I changed that to **`result.Reverse().ToDictionary()`** and now
**`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>>(resBody)`**
works.